# Specify namespaces for controller in web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I was able to specify some name spaces for my razor pages in MVC3 using the web.config file.

Is there a way to do this for the controller's as well so I don't have to keep typing using statements for commonly used ones from an external library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Controllers are normal C# files.
Unlike VB.Net, there is no way to add `using` statements to the entire project.